# How can i handle this scenario

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I am using Backbone.js, unexpectedly i am in the confused position now, because of this scenario..

my test object :

```
test: {
    "links": {
        "nameLink": {
            "name": "name 1",
            "name": "name 2",
            "name": "name 3"
        },
        "ageLink": {
            "age": "1",
            "age": "2",
            "age": "3"
        }
    },
    "data": {
        "element": {
            "project": "project 1",
            "title": "title1",
            "brand": "brand1"
        },
        "element": {
            "project": "project 2",
            "title": "title2",
            "brand": "brand2"
        },
        "element": {
            "project": "project 3",
            "title": "title3",
            "brand": "brand3"
        }
    }
}
```

I do have the josn data from server, it has the project name, links(there is nested links under), time stamps.

1. how can i split the data, and append appropriate UL elements. ( by name, by age ect.)
2. On click on the name, age links, how can sort (by name, age) the datas i appended to body tag? - without sorting the links menu?
3. How can i keep all this updated?

any good suggestion please?

Comment: {
            "name":"name 1",
                    "name":"name 2",
                    "name":"name 3"
        } will be finally {
            "name":"name 3"
       }

Comment: What have you tried? The JSON structure is pretty basic. `data` would be the root element and you would just have to loop and extract each `object` underneath it and create a `View`. Same goes with `links`.